# .NET Core 8 bundling and minifying with WebOptimizer

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8, weboptimizer

I'm starting to work with ASP.NET Core 8 (MVC with Razor), and I'm getting this `b-omgphq2ymd` "tag" added to my HTML elements. What is this? What's the purpose?

From this:

```
<button class="button-menu-mobile open-left waves-light waves-effect" id="btnAction1">
    <i class="dripicons-menu"></i>
</button>
```

To this:

```
<button b-omgphq2ymd="" class="button-menu-mobile open-left waves-light waves-effect" id="btnAction1">
    <i b-omgphq2ymd="" class="dripicons-menu"></i>
</button>
```

At `Program.cs` I'm starting `builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer();` with no special settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is CSS isolation, and here is the official document: [ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

It's a new feature from .NET 6. If you don't want this, you can disable it by modifying the `.csproj` file like below.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    // Add this to disable it
    <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```